# Looking for scsitools (specifically scsiinfo) for Fedora / Centos

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, scsi

I am looking for the scsitools package for fedora. Ubuntu has such a .deb named "scsitools". Specifically I need to find out the vendor, serial number etc. of hard disks connected to a machine.

`scsiinfo -i <device>` and `scsiinfo -s <device>` seem to do the task nicely on debian based systems, but I was unable to find a .rpm package.

Where can I find this package, or is there an other way on Fedora to get this information?

Comment: oh well, never mind. I just copied the executable from a ubuntu machine to my fedora machine and it "just works".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `sg3_utils` package is what you're looking for:

```
Name        : sg3_utils
Version     : 1.25
Release     : 5.el5
Architecture: x86_64
Size        : 1133460
Packager    : None
Group       : Utilities/System
URL         : http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg3_utils.html
Repository  : base
Summary     : Utils for Linux's SCSI generic driver devices + raw devices
Description :
Collection of Linux utilities for devices that use the SCSI command set.
Includes utilities to copy data based on "dd" syntax and semantics (called
sg_dd, sgp_dd and sgm_dd); check INQUIRY data and VPD pages (sg_inq); check
mode and log pages (sginfo, sg_modes and sg_logs); spin up and down
disks (sg_start); do self tests (sg_senddiag); and various other functions.
See the README, CHANGELOG and COVERAGE files. Requires the linux kernel 2.4
series or later. In the 2.4 series SCSI generic device names (e.g. /dev/sg0)
must be used. In the 2.6 series other device names may be used as
well (e.g. /dev/sda).
```

---

```
# sginfo /dev/sda
INQUIRY response (cmd: 0x12)
----------------------------
Device Type                        0
Vendor:                    ATA     
Product:                   WDC WD2502ABYS-0
Revision level:            02.0
```